# Data consolidation

Tags: batch-file, for-loop

I have two text files with following contents:

**file1.txt:**

```
ProcessId  VirtualSize  
5752       74649600     
3932       76843610
1357       90215638
& so on....
```

**file2.txt:**

```
Notepad.exe pid: 3932 Linux
Notepad.exe pid: 1357 Macos
Notepad.exe pid: 5752 Windows
& so on....
```

Now as ,we can see process ids are same (matching) in both the files so i want to generate a consolidated single output file (Matching the processId in both the files) which should have following content:

**Output.txt:**

```
Windows 74649600  
Linux  76843610
Macos  90215638 
& so on....
```

I tried below, its running but not getting required output:

```
@echo off
(for /f "skip=1 tokens=1,2" %%a in (file1.txt) do (
for /f "tokens=5" %%c in ('find " %%a " ^< file2.txt ') do echo %%c %%b
))>Output.txt
```

**EDIT1:**
what should i add if i want to fix/set the first two lines of 'Output.txt' for forever with strings:

```
This output is for first server
Applcation Memory(GB )
```

i.e.:

**Output.txt:**

```
This output is for first server
Applcation Memory(GB)
Windows  74649600  
Linux  76843610
Macos  90215638 
& so on....
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

what about:

```
@echo off

echo This output is for HFM server > out.txt
echo Applcation Memory(GB) >>out.txt

for /f "skip=1 tokens=1,2" %%a in (file1.txt) do (
   for /f "skip=2 tokens=5" %%c in ('find " %%a " file2.txt 2^>nul') do ( 
     echo %%c %%b >>out.txt
  )
)
```

?

Comment: running..but no Output..!

Comment: there was one redundant open bracket .Could you try without `>>out.txt` to see what will happen?

Comment: works fine with me.Are you sure about file names or the content?Do you use relative/paths?Are the files in the same directory?Are there spaces in file names?And the content?

Comment: Answers below..
I am running this batch on Windows 7.
Are you sure about file names or the content? Yes cross checked 
Do you use relative/paths? All files are at same path cd C:\BATCH
Are the files in the same directory? Yes, cd C:\BATCH
Are there spaces in file names? No

Comment: `C:\>sunny.bat`
`GSHFMPRO 74649600`
`USHFMPROD 76843610`
`EUHFMPROD 90215638`  - this is the output without redirection

Comment: and how i can redirect this output to a text file for mailing..?

Comment: the output should be stored in `out.txt` or whatever you want just change or remove `>>out.txt` part...You want to send it to mail now via bat file?

Comment: npocmaka..yes..now its working fine ..!! Wmic is a weird beast sometimes. It adds extra carriage returns in the output sometimes..so i have copied content of file1.txt (which results from wmic command) to another static file..and then run the script.:):..thanks a lot..!!

Comment: Check this thread for the `WMIC` issue : http://www.dostips.com/forum/viewtopic.php?f=3&t=4266

Comment: Pls see **EDIT1** in question.

Comment: you want additional line at -> `Applcation Memory(GB )` ?

Comment: yes..first two lines should be always fixed as `This output is for HFM server`
`Applcation Memory(GB)`

Comment: just add This output is for `echo HFM server>out.file` and `echo Applcation Memory(GB)>>out.file` at the begining. See this for more info about redirection -> http://www.robvanderwoude.com/redirection.php

Answer (score 2):

Your second FOR should be something like the following. The "tokens=5" part selects the 5th token, and nothing else. You need token 3 and 5.

```
(for /f "skip=1 tokens=1,2" %%a in (file1.txt) do (
    for /f "tokens=3,5" %%x in ('find " %%a " ^< file2.txt ') do echo %%b %%y
))
```

If File1 and File2 are long, that script will work but will be really slow.
I wrote a script that reformatted file1 and file2 to have the PID be first thing on each line.
Then, use SORT to organize the file by PID.
Finally, scan the sorted output looking for pairs of lines with matching PID.

A little long, but fairly easy to see how it works.

```
@echo off
SETLOCAL ENABLEEXTENSIONS ENABLEDELAYEDEXPANSION

set INPUT1=file1.txt
set INPUT2=file2.txt
set OUTFILE=Outfile.txt
set TMPFILE=OutfileTMP.txt
set OUT=^>^>%OUTFILE%

if exist %OUTFILE% del %OUTFILE%
if exist %TMPFILE% del %TMPFILE%

call :ReadFile1
call :ReadFile2

sort < %OUTFILE% > %TMPFILE%
del %OUTFILE%
echo This output is for HFM server%OUT%
echo Applcation Memory(GB )%OUT%

set LASTPID=-
set LASTSIZE=-

for /f "tokens=1,2,3" %%a in (%TMPFILE%) do (
    if "%%b"=="1" set LASTPID=%%a&set LASTSIZE=%%c
    if "%%b"=="2" (
        if "%%a"=="!LASTPID!" (
            echo %%c !LASTSIZE! %OUT%
        ) else (
            echo Error: Not Matched: 1:!LASTPID!,!LASTSIZE!, 2:%%a %%c
        )
    )
)

del %TMPFILE%

goto :EOF


:ReadFile1
    for /f "skip=1 tokens=1,2" %%a in (%INPUT1%) do echo %%a 1 %%b %OUT%
    goto :EOF

:ReadFile2
    for /f "tokens=3,5" %%a in (%INPUT2%) do echo %%a 2 %%b %OUT%
    goto :EOF
```

Comment: and i tried modified one of mine also..but still NO OUTPUT..!

Comment: No output at all?
   
What OS are you using?
    
I'm using Windows 7 - but I don't think there is anything version dependent here.

Comment: "Not Matched" means that there is a PID in file1 that isn't found in file2 (or the other way around).    I wasn't sure how you'd want this to be handled.   On the data you gave above though, I tried both and both appeared to work correctly.
    
From that error message I'd guess that File1.txt is not right.

Comment: yes..Joeking..its working fine too..!! Wmic is a weird beast sometimes. It adds extra carriage returns in the output sometimes..so i have copied content of file1.txt (which results from wmic command) to another static file..and then run the script.:):..thanks a lot..!!

Comment: Pls see **EDIT1** in question.

Comment: OK, I added 2 ECHOs that should do that. I've not tested, but its straightforward.